# set ksh return code from java class

Tags: java, ksh

I am calling a java class from a ksh script. Within the java class, it does some error checking, and if an error is found, an email is sent to user. Once the email is sent, I want to return an error code of lets say 11 to the script and fail it based on that.

Currently, my script is successful when it sends the email, but I want to fail it.

Here is some of my ksh script:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java alfaSpecificEditCheck.ValDateCheck $edit_env $FILENAME $USERID
  RC=$?
  echo "RC=$RC"
  if [[ $RC -eq 11 ]]; then
    echo "    ALFA Date has failed the edit. Safe exit."
    echo ${FILEPATH} >> ${BASEDIR}/logs/failed_edit
    echo "    ALFA Date check Failed"
  elif [[ $RC -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "ALFA Date DONE with status $RC ..."
    echo ${FILEPATH} >> ${BASEDIR}/logs/status_fail
    echo "    ALFA Date Failed"
  else
    echo "    ALFA Date Successful" 
  fi
;;
```

Comment: Where is the code for your java file?
You could use `System.exit(11)` from where you want to return the error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment is the correct answer.

```
Where is the code for your java file? You could use System.exit(11) from where you want to return the error code. –  nikhil Oct 27 at 18:17
```